# Running multiple concurrent scripts in node.js 'vm' module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Regarding the 'vm' module in node.js, what is the best approach to instantiating and running scripts in multiple 'vm's? My objective is to create multiple 'vm's and be able to run the scripts in each one concurrently.

Some specific questions I haven't been able to find any answers on:

- Does each 'vm' run on its own thread (or as a separate process)?
- Is a callback mechanism supported so the script can let the calling code know it's done, etc.?
- Are Promises or async/await supported?

I believe the answers are out there, but since 'vm' is such an overused term, I've had a difficult time finding much useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For your use case it is seems better to use [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) module from node.js running scripts in vm is not considered a good practice, and is very hard to ensure security.
>
> **child_process** already has the callback mechanism implemented so you can easily assign handlers on finish.

**In order to answer your questions I made a little script:**

```
const vm = require('vm');

const sandbox = {
  cb: (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
  },
};

const code = `
  function test() {
    cb(null, 'from vm');
  }

  test();
`;
process.nextTick(() => {
  console.log('from event loop');
});
vm.runInNewContext(code, sandbox);
```

The results of the scripts are:

```
from vm
from event loop
```

Which gave me the following conclusions:

> Does each 'vm' run on its own thread (or as a separate process) ?

No, **vm runs synchronously.** if it was running asynchronously the process next tick pushes the `console.log()` in front of libuv queue so we would get `from event loop` first and `from vm`  second.

> Is a callback mechanism supported so the script can let the calling code know it's done, etc.?

Actually it is **not supported natively** but you can manage to write code in the manner I did with `callback` in the sandbox, the single shared state between `vm` and your code is the `global` variable.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the details.